# Automatic Compile and upload to theAppstore

Tags: iphone, compilation

Im trying to set up a system similar to this web site

> http://www.appmakr.com/

My problem is the uploading to the appstore. does anyone has an idea about how to make this process automatic? the only way i can think of is mimicking the web requests and the application loader but is there an interface for that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All web request boil down to simple `PUT/POST/GET/DELETE` etc… calls. Mimicking a user through code is possible and the only way to do this as there is no API. Get an app like [HTTPScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) to determine how to form the requests yourself, then use curl or some other net tool to emulate the requests in code, with the appropriate delay.